# script for variant product with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twig, underscore.js

I develop a little script in javascript but I am a bit blocked, here is my code

HTML :

```
{% for key, pro in variant_name %}
    <p>
        <strong>{{ key }}</strong>
    </p>
    {% for p in pro %}
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{key}" value="{{p}}"> 
            <label>{{ p|upper }}</label>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-primary').on('click', function(){
        var data = new Array();
        var form = $('form').serializeArray();
        var grouped = _.groupBy(form,"name");
        console.log(grouped);
    });
});
```

Here is the result

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0CCR.jpg)

my problem is that I want to have gender like

```
Color: ['Yello', 'Blue']
Brand: ['Adidas']
```

and it is on this point that I am blocked I already tried a lot of idea but I have not found yet, thank you

Comment: It's no really clear what you want to achieve. You want a checkbox with brands, each with a different color? One error I see is that the form tag is in the for loop. You should place this outside the loop, otherwise each checkbox gets its own form.

Comment: no, I want that when I check the color, red, yellow and that I too adidas and when I click the button that has the class btn-primary I get this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, but would have to be adapted to handlebars, if you want to render the items dynamically.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
        var data = $( this ).serializeArray();
        console.log( data );
   
        var formData = {};
        $.each(data, function(idx, val){
           if(!formData[val.name])
           {
              formData[val.name] = [];
           }
           formData[val.name].push(val.value);
        });
     });
  });
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <form>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="yellow" name="color" />Yellow</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue" name="color" />Blue</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="adidas" name="brand" />Adidas</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="puma" name="brand" />Puma</label>
     <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: yes it work but i want to get format like this, for example { "name" : "color"} to transform like Color: ['blue','red'] and Brand: ['puma','adidas'] if it's possible

Comment: I can't creat manualy an array with name color and brand because it's generate dynamically by the
<input type="checkbox" name="{{key}}" value="{{p}}"> i can add a new name in my back end for example Price , etc...

Comment: Update: formData will save data by key.